# Livewire image upload fails on production server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, vps, laravel-livewire

I've deployed my laravel project to vps server(ubuntu) on top of LEMP stack. Everything works fine with livewire, except image uploading.

> Image uploading itself works fine on my local environment

When I try to upload image Livewire throws validation error saying `The icon failed to upload.`

This is becuse of Livewire can't create `livewire-tmp` folder. I've created that folder myself and gave it 755 permission, but still it's not working. I've also published livewire config file and changed some configurations, but still the same.

I don't know why Livewire can not create `livewire-temp` folder and store temporary files in it. Maybe it's something to do with nginx server configuration. So I am sharing my ngnix configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/west-hospital-admin/public;
    #root /home/west/west-hospital-admin/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
    }
    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I'm placing my project's folder and file permissions if in case is needed. It's likely to be a permission issue.

[image]

```
storage/app/public folder
```

> Note, that Livewire itself didn't create the `livewire-tmp` folder. I
> created it and gave 755 permission to it.

[image]

`public` folder, with symbolic link to `storage/app/public` folder

[image]

I would very appreciate it if someone who knows why Livewire can not handle uploading can share their knowledge with me.

Comment: Could be upload limit. Try to add this line to nginx config `client_max_body_size 100M;`, where 100M is desired limit in Mb (100 Mb in my example). Also check both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini` file

Comment: It's not about upload limit, because there is some sections which have normal image upload. But, I've tried `client_max_body_size 100M;` and it is the same.

Comment: Linux environments are usually pretty locked down with permissions, and its typically why you are seeing errors with uploading in one environment and not locally.

Comment: I guess it's about permissions, but I've already given 755 permission to storage and public folder recursively. But that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solution

1. Go to the `vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Controllers/FileUploadHandler.php` and comment this line `abort_unless(request()->hasValidSignature(), 401);`
2. Go to the `vendor/livewire/livewire/src/TemporaryUploadedFile.php` and instead of this `$tmpfile = tmpfile();`, write this:

   ```
    $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '');
    $tmpFile = fopen($tmpfname, 'w');
   ```
3. Go to `public` folder of your application and create `livewire` folder.(`mkdir livewire`) After that, go to that directory and from there you will create a symbolic link, pointing from `public/livewire/preview-file` to your application's `storage/app/public/livewire-tmp` folder:

`ln -s preview-file ../../storage/app/public/livewire-tmp`

And remember, you need to give 755 permissions to folders, that are inside `storage/app/public` folder.

> Explanation

1. We need to comment that line, because it checks whether you have a `ssl certificate` or not. If not, it will abort the request. If you have a ssl certificate, you can skip this step.
2. In this step, we create `temporary file` and give write access.
3. Final step is just creating a `symbolic link`. We need to create this `symbolic link` because, when uploading a file, Livewire creates a temporary file with that url.

Comment: Just step 1 was enough for me. I Will of course lose this change should the vendor get updated. It does allow me to complete the job on dev so upvoted

Comment: the problem is coming for me on the AWS *The file failed to upload.* whatever the changes we make in the vendor folder it's gonna git ignore it anyway right then what is the solutions

Comment: Modifying vendor files is a BAD practice. The related issue is due to laravel TrustedProxies middleware configuration and must be handled in the correct way, not by commenting vendor files

Answer (score 1):

@toghrul-nasirli helped with step 1, but in my case I have to use 775 instead of 755 on Ubuntu and skipped steps 2,3. Then from project root I allowed to upload images for website visitor:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 public/assets/imgs
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data public/assets/imgs
```

ps. don't use 77**7**